# Lowercase true/false keywords in Aptana PHP editor

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3

Is it possible to make TRUE/FALSE autocompletion lowercase in Aptana?

Comment: I'd suggest adding a new ticket here: http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa. Note that the bug tracking system requires the creation of an account before you can add bugs. Another option might be to create snippets in the PHP ruble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems like there is no such option. So I've created feature request at Aptana's bug tracker: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3585